# React-Router rendering props

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using react router for my project and I need to render separate props (the introduction) to another component which is accessible through my Card component. Currently, each card has a title of a blog, when the "Read more" button is clicked , I want the article page to render showing the introduction for each blog, but nothing is showing.

Blog

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import Article from './Article'
import Card from './BlogCards/Card'

function Blog(props) {


    const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([])
    const [image, setImage] = useState()
    const [selectedBlog, setSelectedBlog] = useState(blogs)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://cdn.contentful.com...")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>
          setBlogs(data.items)
       
        )
      }, []) 

      console.log(blogs)
    return (
        <div className="container">
        {selectedBlog !== null ? blogs.map((blog =>
          <>
          <Card title={blog.fields.title} introduction={blog.fields.introduction} setSelectedBlog={selectedBlog} />
             </>   
        )): 
        
        <Article title={blogs.find(d => d.fields.title === selectedBlog)}   />
        }

        </div>
    )
}

export default Blog
```

Card

```
import {Link, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Article from '../Article'

function Card(props) {
  
  console.log(props)
    return (
            
            <div className="container">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-12">
      <article className="blog-card">
        <div className="blog-card__background">
          <div className="card__background--wrapper">
            <div className="card__background--main" style={{backgroundImage: "url('https://i.pinimg.com/564x/7f/bb/97/7fbb9793b574c32f5d28cae0ea5c557f.jpg')"}}/>
              <div className="card__background--layer"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

        <div className="blog-card__head">
        </div>
        <div className="blog-card__info">
          <h5>{props.title}</h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque vero libero voluptatibus earum? Alias dignissimos quo cum, nulla esse facere atque, blanditiis doloribus at sunt quas, repellendus vel? Et, hic!</p>
        <Link to='/article'>
        <button >read more</button>
        </Link>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
        <Route exact path="/article">
          <Article introduction={props.introduction} />
        </Route>
</div>

    )   
}

export default Card
```

Article

```
import React from 'react'
import './Article.css'

function Article(props) {
console.log(props)
    return (
        <div>
             <p>{props.introduction}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Article
```

This his how my routes are set up:

```
<Route path='/blog'>
 <Blog />
</Route> 
<Route path='/article'>
  <Article />
</Route>
```

Comment: We would need to see how you are setting up your routes and how `Blog` is being rendered. Chances are if you are navigating to `"/article"` you're no longer on the route that renders the parent component so the nested route to render `Article` is no longer mounted.

Comment: ive edited my question. Routes are set up in App.js

Comment: Am i rendering Article.in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `introduction` prop isn't passed to the `Article` component rendered by the `Route` in your main router in `App`.

```
<Route path='/article'>
  <Article /> // <-- no extra props
</Route>
```

You are rendering a second route within the `Card` component that will never match because the `Card` is rendered by `Blog` which is rendered on the `path='/blog'` path, so `"/article"` won't ever match (*especially "exactly"*).

## Solution

A simple solution would be to send a specific `introduction` in route state for the transition to the "/article" path.

Update the link in `Card` component to send the title and introduction in route state.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: '/article',
    state: {
      title: props.title,
      introduction: props.introduction
    }
  }}
>
  <button>read more</button>
</Link>
```

Remove the extraneous `<Route exact path="/article">` from `Card`.

Unless you have two ***different*** `Article` components, you likely want to remove the other `Article` component from `Blog` that a `title` prop is passed to and let the main router render the article.

In `Article` use the `useLocation` React hook to access the route state.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function Article(props) {
  const { state = {} } = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{state.introduction}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: @ShuibAbdillahi Yeah, unless you've some other in-scope values you want to pass as props to `Article` from `App` the blog values will be sent in the route state. I noticed you render an `Article` component in a few places, I updated my answer to suggest rendering *only* the single one by the main router/route. If issue persists can you try creating a *running* codesandbox that we can take a look at?

Comment: yeah, the other Article was a mistake, it works perfectly now thanks